# Online Repository for Google App Engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, repository, online-repository

I have been writing a web app for some time now for Google App Engine and I just now have gotten a partner on the project.  I have been working in Eclipse and writing in Python and I need to share the project with him.

What kind of repository would you suggest or could I use to share the code base with my partner?  I have looked at some options like Mercurial or Git but is there anything that I can have directly update my files in the Eclipse development folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recomend you to create a Git repo and use [Egit](http://www.eclipse.org/resources/resource.php?id=528), very nice git plugin for eclipse. You can set up a repo in [Google Code](http://code.google.com) or any other website that you like. I have sources in [Bean Stalk App](http://www.beanstalkapp.com) and [bitbucket](http://www.bitbucket.org). They both work fine with git!

Comment: alright great that is exactly what I was looking for